# Need SQL query for below requirement

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help to get SQL select query to get my result like the table in the below picture.
[image]

Comment: I won't post a answer because this seems like a home work. You can achieve by UNION of two selections.

Comment: Any specific reason you had two columns for Employee ID and Name each at first place? If not just change your table creation logic and insert data accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using union all into subquery:

```
select * from (
   select RequestId, Emp_id1 'Emp_Id', Emp_Name1 'Emp_Name' from tbl
   union all
   select RequestId, Emp_id2 'Emp_Id', Emp_Name2 'Emp_Name' from tbl
) as a
order by RequestId
```

Here is demo on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad5fb1680f32c66c2e3f59254b0c5e49)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your first table is A.
Pseudo code:

```
select request_id, emp_id, emp_name from (
    select request_id, emp_id_1 as emp_id, emp_name_1 as emp_name from A
    union all
    select request_id, emp_id_2 as emp_id, emp_name_2 as emp_name from A
) B order by request_id asc;
```